# Deriving variance from the expected deviation from the mean of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter, stochastic-filtering

I know the expected absolute deviation from the mean of a normal distribution $E[|X-\mu_x|]$. From this I want to derive the variance $\sigma^2$ of said distribution. This is done to tune a filter of $X$ that expects an estimate of the current variance at each time step. I don't know the sign of the deviation, just the magnitude.

I identified two approaches to derive the variance, but I am unsure which one is the better estimate of the variance:

**Approach 1 - Re-arranging the mean absolute deviation (MAD):**

Here I interpret $E[|X-\mu_x|]$ as the known expected deviation from the mean. For a normal distribution:
$$E[|X-\mu_x|] = \sigma_x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

The MAD can be re-arranged to yield the variance:

$${\sigma_x}^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot {E[|X-\mu_x|]}^2$$

**Approach 2 - Calculating ${\sigma_x}^2$ directly from one sample**

$${\sigma_x}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu_x)^2$$

with n=1:

$${\sigma_x}^2 = (X_i -\mu_x)^2$$

Which approach is *valid*? The argument for approach 1 seems to be straight forward. In approach $2$ I can't even apply Bessel's correction without dividing by zero (And I don't know the mean, just the deviation from it!).

Edit:

To clarify my use case:
I know the deviation, which is derived from a separate measurement. I trust this measurement to be the expected deviation (mean absolute deviation). I do not know the sign of the deviation and as such can not directly correct X. Instead I am filtering it with a variable estimate of the variance.

Comment: Not following.  Why would you think it was a good idea to estimate the variance by taking a single sample?

Comment: @lulu Because it is all I have. I know the deviation, which is derived from a separate measurement. It is effectively a single sample of the deviation. At the same time I trust this measurement to be the expected deviation (mean absolute deviation). I do not know the sign of the deviation and as such can not directly correct $X$. Instead I am filtering it with a variable estimate of the variance.

Comment: I don't understand.  You don't have a sample. All you have is MAD (the mean absolute deviation).  Indeed, you have neither a sample nor the mean, so I'm not sure how you aim to compute your formula in part $2$.

Comment: I think you are confused...the mean absolute deviation is positive, always, just like the variance (ok, they can be $0$ for trivial distributions, but they can't ever be negative).

Comment: I am aware that the MAD can only be positive. I wanted to pre-empt the trivial solution of "So you have a measurement of the deviation. Why don't you correct your state with that?". Indeed, I only know the absolute deviation. My filter expects a variance. Do you agree then, that Approach 1 is sound?

Comment: Approach $1$ is correct if you know the distribution is normal.  As I say, I don't understand the second approach at all.

Comment: Thank you! It is very well possible that approach 2 stems from a misunderstanding on my part - as you already pointed out.